# To Find a map between the Torus and the Circle which is not nullhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am trying to find a map between the torus and the circle which is not nullhomotopic.

There is a theorem that says

> > Let $p:E\rightarrow B$ be a covering map. Let $f:Y\rightarrow B$ be a continuous map. The map can be lifted to a map $\tilde{f}:Y\rightarrow E$ if and only if,  $f_*(\pi_1(Y))\subseteq p_*(\pi_1(E))$.

My idea/guess:

We can see the torus as $S^1\times S^1$. We can use the projection map $f:S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^1$ from the first coordinate onto the circle. Since $f$ is surjective we have 
$$f_*(\pi_1(Y))\subsetneq p_*(\pi_1(E)).$$
So I guess that the map $f$ should be non-nullhomotopic. But how to prove this?

Comment: Ask yourself: What would be the consequences for $f_*$ if $f$ was nullhomotopic? (and forget about covering maps.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have $f$ is projection from $S^1\times S^1\to S^1$. Define $g$ in the
reverse direction by $g(z)=(z,*)$ where $*$ is your basepoint. Then $f\circ g$ is the identity on $S^1$. So it induces the identity on $\pi_1(S^1,*)$.
So some element of $\pi_1(S^1\times S^1)$ is mapped by $f_*$ to the generator of
$\pi_1(S^1,*)$, an infinite cyclic group.

Comment: So this is the contradiction: As $f$ is nullhomotopic $f_*$ is the trivial homomorphism. Hence $f_*\circ g_*$ should be trivial, but it is identity. Am I right?

Comment: I think that's it! @learning_math

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown 
Are you reasoning by contradiction? I can not understand what you have done. Could you explain better? Thank you.